# Символ юникода для имени хоста

Tags: c#, httpclient

Могу ли я каким то образом, запустив httpListener по префиксу "http://+:8080", после этого послать на него запрос? Или же символы юникода нельзя использовать в хосте?

Comment: Эээ, а что вы подразумеваете под «символами юникода»?

Comment: Вероятно, не так выразился. Я создал и запустил httplistener с префиксом "http://+:8080", и весь вопрос в том что я не могу отправить на него запрос, так как WebClient говорит что не может распознать имя хоста, видимо такое имя хоста "+" для него не валидно. И вот мой вопрос, это вообще возможно, сделать так чтобы это работало?

Answer (score 0):

+, означает что он может принимать запросы с любого IP, а в WebCliente вы должны указать Ip и порт сервера(в вашем случае httplistener)

Comment: Скоре + означает, что listener будет принимать все запросы на данном порту, независимо от других префиксов, в отличии от *, когда принимаются запросы, если URI не совпал с другими префиксами. Так что не обязательно указывать именно IP

Comment: @PrimusSingularis да это так, вы правы. Я решил, что мой ответ будет понятен автору и он непротиворечив.

Answer (score 0):

Да, при запросе имя хоста http://+:8080 не валидно, так как + это не имя, а спец символ, означающий, что HttpListener принимает все запросы на порт 8080 для любого URI, т.е. для HttpListener'а это валидная строка, а для клиента нет. При запросе вам надо указать имя хоста, на котором запущен listener, если запускаете в локальной сети, можете указать IP адрес или имя машины (http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/), если с той же машины, localhost (http://localhost:8080)